# Post Data to ASP.NET Web API using onBlur

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, onblur

In my ASP.NET Web API application I have a 'Save Contact' form as follows:

```
<form id="saveContactForm" method="post">
    <h3>Create a new Contact</h3>
    <p>
        <label for="contactId">Contact Id:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Id" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="contactName">Contact Name:</label>
        <input id="Name" type="text" name="Name" />
    </p>
    <input type="button" id="saveContact" value="Save" />
</form>
```

I have the following jQuery which successfully handles the 'Save' button click:

```
$('#saveContact').click(function () {
    var nm = $('#contactName').val();
    var id = $('#contactId').val();    
    $.post("api/contact",
          $("#saveContactForm").serialize(),
          function (value) {
              $('#contacts').append('<li>' + value.Name + '</li>');
          },
          "json"
    );
});
```

and saves the new Contact.

I would like to extend this functionality by attaching an onblur event to the 'Name' input field.

By way of a test, this works:

```
$("#Name").blur(function () {
    setTimeout("callafterSomeTime()", 1000);
});    
function callafterSomeTime() {
    alert('Hi');
}
```

However, this fails:

```
$("#Name").blur(function () {
    $.post("api/contact",
          $("#saveContactForm").serialize(),
          function (value) {
              $('#contacts').append('<li>' + value.Name + '</li>');
          },
          "json"
    );
});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Can you add a `.fail()` handler on your post? The answer might lie within.

Answer (score 1):

In your jQuery post you should add a forward slash in the directory path,

$.post("/api/contact",

instead of

$.post("api/contact",

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use "on" instead "click" and "blur" events. Eg:

```
$( '#saveContact' ).on( 'click', function() {} );
```

In the last function (blur event), try `console.log( value );` for verify if "value" returns the expected.